# Formula to count specific criteria in data set and another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am trying to get a count of specific value within a data set that match the name which is in another column.  Basically I have a data set with different values along a time schedule.

I want to create a summary that counts the total number of each specific value per each unique individual.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you try  `=countifs` or `=countif`?

Comment: if I understand your question correctly you should look into using countif(s)

Answer (score 2):

Adjust your references to suit your data.  The following formula is based on the picture below.

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX($B$7:$I$9,MATCH($A2,$A$7:$A$9,0),0),B$1)
```

With the proper reference locking, the above formula was placed in B2 and copied down and to the right as required.

Use the INDEX function to return to the entire row of data you are looking to count in.  0 will tell index that the entire row is returned.

Match is used to determine which of the rows to look in. The 0 tell match to look for an exact match.

now that you have the row of data you want to count in, use the COUNTIF function to count based on your matching criteria which is the header.  By default COUNTIF uses and exact match = if no other comparison operation is given.

[image: POC]

#### Alternative

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`.  Depending on the size of your data and how often you repeat the formula, it may bog down your system as it will perform array like calculations.  The following formula is based on the picture below and is placed in F3 and copied down and to the right:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$8:$A$10=$A3)*($B$8:$I$10=F$2))
```

[image: POC2]

#### Alternative 2

The array formula of sumproduct which requires <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when finishing your formula and comes with all the same warnings as using SUMPRODUCT is:

```
=SUM(($A$8:$A$10=$A4)*($B$8:$I$10=J$2))
```

You will know you have entered is correctly as { } will show around your formula in the formula bar.  Note these cannot be added manually.  The ranges are based on the picture below.

[image: POC3]